# How can I compare two lists in prolog, returning true if the second list is made of every other element of list one?

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

I would solve it by comparing the first index of the first list and adding 2 to the index. But I do not know how to check for indexes in prolog. 
Also, I would create a counter that ignores what is in the list when the counter is an odd number (if we start to count from 0).
Can you help me?
Example:
everyOther([1,2,3,4,5],[1,3,5]) is true, but everyOther([1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3]) is not.

Comment: This is not the way to work with Prolog lists. Can you think how would you compare just two lists (without the skipping)?

Comment: Example, please! How would one use it?

Comment: I was thinking about comparing the head of both lists. But if I want the every other element of list 1, I do not know how to do it without skipping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We present three logically-pure definitions even though you only need one—variatio delectat:)

1. Two mutually recursive predicates `list_oddies/2` and `skipHead_oddies/2`:

   ```
   list_oddies([],[]).
   list_oddies([X|Xs],[X|Ys]) :-
      skipHead_oddies(Xs,Ys).

   skipHead_oddies([],[]).
   skipHead_oddies([_|Xs],Ys) :-
      list_oddies(Xs,Ys).
   ```
2. The recursive `list_oddies/2` and the non-recursive `list_headless/2`:

   ```
   list_oddies([],[]).
   list_oddies([X|Xs0],[X|Ys]) :-
      list_headless(Xs0,Xs),
      list_oddies(Xs,Ys).

   list_headless([],[]).
   list_headless([_|Xs],Xs).
   ```
3. A "one-liner" which uses [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  `foldl/4` in combination with [Prolog lambdas](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord):

   ```
   :- use_module(library(lambda)).

   list_oddies(As,Bs) :-
      foldl(\X^(I-L)^(J-R)^(J is -I,( J < 0 -> L = [X|R] ; L = R )),As,1-Bs,_-[]).
   ```

All three implementations avoid the creation of useless choicepoints, but they do it differently:

- #1 and #2 use first-argument indexing.
- #3 uses `(->)/2` and `(;)/2` in a logically safe way—using `(<)/2` as the condition.

---

Let's have a look at the queries @WouterBeek gave [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30036450/4609915)!

```
?- list_oddies([],[]),
   list_oddies([a],[a]),
   list_oddies([a,b],[a]),
   list_oddies([a,b,c],[a,c]),
   list_oddies([a,b,c,d],[a,c]),
   list_oddies([a,b,c,d,e],[a,c,e]),
   list_oddies([a,b,c,d,e,f],[a,c,e]),
   list_oddies([a,b,c,d,e,f,g],[a,c,e,g]),
   list_oddies([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h],[a,c,e,g]).
true.                                           % all succeed deterministically
```

Thanks to [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity), we get logically sound answers—even with the most general query:

```
?- list_oddies(Xs,Ys).
  Xs = [],                        Ys = []
; Xs = [_A],                      Ys = [_A]
; Xs = [_A,_B],                   Ys = [_A]
; Xs = [_A,_B,_C],                Ys = [_A,_C]
; Xs = [_A,_B,_C,_D],             Ys = [_A,_C]
; Xs = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E],          Ys = [_A,_C,_E]
; Xs = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F],       Ys = [_A,_C,_E]
; Xs = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F,_G],    Ys = [_A,_C,_E,_G]
; Xs = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F,_G,_H], Ys = [_A,_C,_E,_G]
...
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two base cases and one recursive case:

1. From an empty list you cannot take any odd elements.
2. From a list of length 1 the only element it contains is an odd element.
3. For lists of length >2 we take the first element but not the second one; the rest of the list is handled in recursion.

The code looks as follows:

```
odd_ones([], []).
odd_ones([X], [X]):- !.
odd_ones([X,_|T1], [X|T2]):-
  odd_ones(T1, T2).
```

Notice that in Prolog we do not need to maintain an explicit index that has to be incremented etc. We simply use matching: `[]` matches the empty list, `[X]` matches a singleton list, and `[X,_|T]` matches a list of length >2. The `|` separates the first two elements in the list from the rest of the list (called the "tail" of the list). `_` denotes an unnamed variable; we are not interested in even elements.
Also notice the cut (`!`) which removes the idle choicepoint for the second base case.

Example of use:

```
?- odd_ones([], X).
X = [].
?- odd_ones([a], X).
X = [a].
?- odd_ones([a,b], X).
X = [a].
?- odd_ones([a,b,c], X).
X = [a, c].
?- odd_ones([a,b,c,d], X).
X = [a, c].
?- odd_ones([a,b,c,d,e], X).
X = [a, c, e].
```

Comment: @repeat Indeed, thanks for improving upon my answer!